# Google Drive: Automatically convert files on upload?

Tags: import, google-drive-api, file-conversion

Is it possible to get Google Drive to **automatically** convert uploaded documents to the native format?

I know it works with **manual** upload (i.e. Google Drive can auto-convert files you upload via the website), but I want to avoid having to upload every file by hand.

I'd prefer to use the API, or better yet, dump the files in my `~/Google Drive` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the API, you can pass the `convert=true` parameter to [`files.insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert). The uploaded file will attempt to be converted to a native Google Docs format.

Comment: Sounds like a winner to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905363/create-file-with-google-drive-api-v3-javascript/44527113?noredirect=1#answer-35182924). Note you can upload a text file or a csv file and set its content type to google doc or google sheets respectively, and google will attempt to convert it. I have tested this for text -> doc and it works.  You will need to set the `const contentType` at the start of the code to one of the [supported google mimetypes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types).