# Create File with Google Drive Api v3 (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I want to create a file with content using Google Drive API v3. I have authenticated via OAuth and have the Drive API loaded. Statements like the following work (but produce a file without content):

```
gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    "name": "settings",
}).execute();
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to create a file that has a content. I cannot find a JavaScript example using Drive API v3. Are there some special parameters that I need to pass?

For simplicity, assume that I have a String like '{"name":"test"}' that is in JSON format that should be the content of the created file.

Comment: Check this documentation, I know is for v2 but the process is very similar. You would need to change the version in the url to v3 and the parameter according to the v3 ( eg. instead of 'title'  use 'name') https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples

Comment: Thanks for the link, but from I think this is somewhat against the spirit of using the library (at least in v3): In no other case do I have to build the request myself. Here I have to choose thinks like I want it to be a 'POST' request and have to concatenate things into a long string delimited by a boundary. I think the point of v3 was to avoid these things and I guess there should be another way to do it.

Comment: Take a look at [upload.js](https://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample) from some devs at Google.  I have a modified version for drive v3 api [here](https://gist.github.com/DrPaulBrewer/eaea4ad927389643e56ce566d4ed513e)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here is the solution with `gapi.client.drive`,

```
var parentId = '';//some parentId of a folder under which to create the new folder
var fileMetadata = {
  'name' : 'New Folder',
  'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
  'parents': [parentId]
};
gapi.client.drive.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
}).then(function(response) {
  switch(response.status){
    case 200:
      var file = response.result;
      console.log('Created Folder Id: ', file.id);
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Error creating the folder, '+response);
      break;
    }
});
```

you'll need to [connect/authorise](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) with either of the [following scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

EDIT: it is possible to create google files (doc, sheets and so on) by changing the `mimeType` from `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` to one of the supported [google mime types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types).  **HOWEVER**, as of now it not possible to upload any content into created files.

To upload files, use the [solution provided by @Geminus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905363/create-file-with-google-drive-api-v3-javascript/44527113?noredirect=1#answer-35182924).  Note you can upload a text file or a csv file and set its content type to google doc or google sheets respectively, and google will attempt to convert it.  I have tested this for text -> doc and it works.

Comment: This creates a folder, not a file, though.

Comment: this creates a folder actually, I will post shortly the solution for a file

Comment: @DavidGiven, I just edited my answer, you can create a doc/sheet or any other supported file type, but you cannot use `gapi.client.drive.files.create` to actually upload content.

Comment: I did not edit your answer. I edited my comment above (because I misread your code and the comment was wrong).

Comment: Ah, yeah! English is a stupid language, isn't it? Anyway, I appreciate the help; I'd still like an actual solution here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146566/discussion-between-aurovrata-and-david-given).

Comment: After a long long search this is the only piece of code which works! Thanks mate. :)

Answer (score 28):

Unfortunately, I have not found an answer using only the google drive api, instead I followed Gerardo's comment and used the google request api. Below is a function that uploads a file to google drive.

```
var createFileWithJSONContent = function(name,data,callback) {
  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

  const contentType = 'application/json';

  var metadata = {
      'name': name,
      'mimeType': contentType
    };

    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n\r\n' +
        data +
        close_delim;

    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files',
        'method': 'POST',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
        },
        'body': multipartRequestBody});
    if (!callback) {
      callback = function(file) {
        console.log(file)
      };
    }
    request.execute(callback);
}
```

Comment: If you ever found out how to do this via `gapi.client.drive`, I'd love to know.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was going crazy.

Comment: I have file in my folder and upload using URL how to do this ?

Comment: How can I then get the contents of this file?

Comment: @DavidGiven posted a solution with `gapi.client.drive`

Comment: I know it has been a few years since this answer, but just want to add that this worked for me. Thank you so much! Note that you can also upload html (which gets converted into a google doc) in this way.

Answer (score 12):

Using `gapi.client.drive`, it is not possible to upload file content. You can only upload metadata.

Instead it is recommended to work directly with the Google REST API. This solution uses a `FormData` object to build the multipart form body, which simplifies the implementation, and `gapi.auth.getToken()` to retrieve the required access token. The solution also works with **Google shared drives**:

```
var fileContent = "sample text"; // fileContent can be text, or an Uint8Array, etc.
var file = new Blob([fileContent], {type: "text/plain"});
var metadata = {
    "name": "yourFilename",
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "parents": ["folder id or 'root'"], // Google Drive folder id
};

var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' }));
form.append('file', file);

fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }),
    body: form,
}).then((res) => {
    return res.json();
}).then(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: I am a bit late to the party, but do you have a source for the part where it's not possible to upload file content with gapi? I am looking at the documentation and am confused? @mario-varchmin

Comment: @bouffelec I keep only working code, not code, that is not working. I am not saying that an upload is not possible with gapi, in fact my proposed solution is using gapi. What I meant is that this was not possible (at the time of writing) using the Google API Client Library for JavaScript, which Geminus was having problems with.

Answer (score -1):

this works fine usin v3:

```
        var fileMetadata = {
            'name' : 'MaxBarrass',
            'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
        };

        gapi.client.drive.files.create({
            resource: fileMetadata,
            fields: 'id'
        }).execute(function(resp, raw_resp) {
            console.log('Folder Id: ', resp.id);
        });
```

Comment: this appears to be for creating a folder, not a file.

Comment: yeah you can make folder with it as... it does say "files.create" in "gapi.client.drive.files.create", its all nodes in the end so and they are more like files than folders...

Comment: I realise that, but the question specifically asked about creating files. So it's hard to see why an example showing the creation of a folder would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
/*  Now to create a new file */ 
function insertNewFile(folderId) 
{   
    var content = " ";  
    var FolderId = ""; 
    var contentArray = new Array(content.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) 
    {
        contentArray[i] = content.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(contentArray);
    var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'text/plain'});     
    insertFile(blob, fileInserted, folderId); 
} 
function fileInserted(d) 
{   
    setPercent("100");   
    var FI = FolderId;  
    if(FI !== myRootFolderId)
    {           
        insertFileIntoFolder(FI, d.id);         
        removeFileFromFolder(d.parents[0].id,d.id);     
    }   
    openFile(d.id); 
} 
function insertFileIntoFolder(folderId, fileId) 
{   
    var body = {'id': folderId};   
    var request = gapi.client.drive.parents.insert({
        'fileId': fileId,
        'resource': body   });   
    request.execute(function(resp) { }); 
 }
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/mkaminsky11/8624150

Comment: You missed out `insertFile()`, which is actually doing the work; it's the same as @Geminus' answer above, using an explicit post to upload the data.