# Upload file to google drive using javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I searched lot and found nothing about how to send files. Even in google documentation there is nothing about sending file using Javascript sdk.

See here https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

So right now I'm converting the nodeJs script to javascript. And they used fs to get the readstream. And I have no idea how to do that in javascript. Closet I can get to this...

```
var file = uploadButton.files[0]
var fileName = uploadButton.files[0].name

var fileMetadata = {
  'name': fileName
};

var media = {
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
  body: file
};

gapi.client.drive.files.create({
   resource: fileMetadata,
   media: media.result,
   fields: 'id'
}).execute();
```

Above code creates the empty file with then fileName and no content inside on it.

Comment: Is it the same behavior regardless of file type (mimeType)? Have you tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34905363/4625829)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload a file to your google drive you need to use a google request object and 'POST' the file.  You can see an example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905363/create-file-with-google-drive-api-v3-javascript/44527113?noredirect=1#answer-35182924).  Keep in mind that you need to get your [API keys](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) in order to initialise your google drive client object.