# multipart/related request body for Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, multipart

I am trying to create a pdf file on my google drive folder that I have downloaded through Gmail API, using a multipart/related request and Google Auth Library.

[image]

So this is the object the Gmail API is sending to me. I am able to create a pdf file out of it, using [base64topdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64topdf).

My issue is to send this file to my google drive folder.

This is my base code :

```
const response = await auth.request({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': `multipart/related; boundary=${boundary}`
    },
    params: {
        uploadType: 'multipart'
    },
    data
});
```

I have tried different ways to send my file through the data object with the help of [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload), and by looking into the code of [google's node API](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) which do the following:

```
params.uploadType = 'multipart';
const multipart = [
    {'Content-Type': 'application/json', body: JSON.stringify(resource)}, {
        'Content-Type':
        media.mimeType || (resource && resource.mimeType) || defaultMime,
        body: media.body  // can be a readable stream or raw string!
    }
];
const boundary = uuid.v4();
const finale = `--${boundary}--`;
const rStream = new stream.PassThrough();
const isStream = isReadableStream(multipart[1].body);
headers['Content-Type'] = `multipart/related; boundary=${boundary}`;
for (const part of multipart) {
    const preamble =
        `--${boundary}\r\nContent-Type: ${part['Content-Type']}\r\n\r\n`;
    rStream.push(preamble);
    if (typeof part.body === 'string') {
        rStream.push(part.body);
        rStream.push('\r\n');
    } else {
        part.body.pipe(rStream, {end: false});
        part.body.on('end', () => {
            rStream.push('\r\n');
            rStream.push(finale);
            rStream.push(null);
        });
    }
}
if (!isStream) {
    rStream.push(finale);
    rStream.push(null);
}
options.data = rStream;
```

I've tried using Buffers, plain strings... I always end up having a `Error: Malformed multipart body.` or a PDF that only displays the data of the Gmail API object as a plain string.

Cannot find anything on how to do it with javascript and not using form-data! Can anyone help me out?

Comment: have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35182924/1841839

Comment: @DalmTo I've just tried, my file is uploaded but it's just a pdf which content is the data of the Gmail API object as a plain string. I think this is the issue, I have to convert this data string into something else, but I don't figure out what.

Comment: even tried to decode the base64 string, and send it to google drive. didn't work as well.