# How can I save a JSON config file to a user's google drive & retrieve it again?

Tags: javascript, json, frontend, drive

I have a HTML5 web app that saves user configuration in a JSON format.
At the moment the Data is saved in LocalStorage.

I've seen other apps backup files to google drive (such as draw.io).

[image]

I want to save the users config file in their google drive and be able to retrieve it again.

Can this be done in the frontend utilising JavaScript and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) and [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) methods of the Google Drive API. The examples on those pages have Javascript tabs which you may be able to use as a starting point.

Comment: Do you have any examples using the `v3` version? Because the v3 doesn't have. This looks like a simple thing, yet it's very complicated to set up because of the lack in the documentation.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905363/create-file-with-google-drive-api-v3-javascript/44527113?noredirect=1#answer-35182924). It looks like for v3, you might have to assemble your request manually.