# Upload JSON data with Google Drive API in the browser

Tags: google-drive-api

The Google Drive API lets us upload JSON files like that:

```
const fileMetadata = {
  name: "config.json",
};

const media = {
  mimeType: "application/json",
  body: fs.createReadStream("files/config.json"),
};

const file = await gapi.client.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: "id",
});

console.log("File Id:", file.data.id);
```

This works fine in Node.js, but i want this to run in the browser, however, when i pass the media argument, with the body set to a string, an empty Untitled file is created without any extension.
The filename only works when media is not present.

My question is: How to pass data for a JSON from a string, so it can be read later?

I already tried creating the file and updating it later with its ID.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
body: new Blob([JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2)], {
            type: "application/json",
          })
```

and did run into the same problem in the browser as you (untitled, empty file).

I ended up using plain POST, see [Google Drive API creates empty 'Untitled' file with browser version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67326520/google-drive-api-creates-empty-untitled-file-with-browser-version)

In the end plain HTTP is easier to understand and better documented by Google.