# Get INVALID_REQUEST-MISSING_OR_INVALID_REQUEST_BODY when trying to upload file evidence via PayPal API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to upload evidence file by the documentation of PayPal API (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/v1/)

But I get error 400 - INVALID_REQUEST, MISSING_OR_INVALID_REQUEST_BODY.

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. This is part of the code that produces form-data:

```
const str = {
evidences: [
{
evidence_type: "PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT",
evidence_info: {
tracking_info: [
{
carrier_name: "FEDEX",
tracking_number: "122533485"
}
]
},
notes: "Test"
}
]
}
const data = JSON.stringify(str);

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('input', data);
formData.append('type', "application/json");
formData.append('file1', fileBuffer, {
filename: "@maor.pdf"
});
```

And this is the log of the request:

```
{
method: 'post',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW',
Authorization: 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXX'
},
body: FormData {
_overheadLength: 364,
_valueLength: 75083,
_valuesToMeasure: [],
writable: false,
readable: true,
dataSize: 0,
maxDataSize: 2097152,
pauseStreams: true,
_released: false,
_streams: [
'----------------------------736530077015435126960318\r\n' +
'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input"\r\n' +
'\r\n',
'{"evidences":[{"evidence_type":"PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT","evidence_info":{"tracking_info":[{"carrier_name":"FEDEX","tracking_number":"122533485"}]},"notes":"Test"}]}',
[Function: bound ],
'----------------------------736530077015435126960318\r\n' +
'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"\r\n' +
'\r\n',
'application/json',
[Function: bound ],
'----------------------------736530077015435126960318\r\n' +
'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="@maor.pdf"\r\n' +
'Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n' +
'\r\n',
<Buffer 25 50 44 46 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 2f 50 61 67 65 0a 2f 50 61 72 65 6e 74 20 31 20 30 20 52 0a 2f 4d 65 64 69 ... 74855 more bytes>,
[Function: bound ]
],
_currentStream: null,
_insideLoop: false,
_pendingNext: false,
_boundary: '--------------------------736530077015435126960318'
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are posting form data. The PayPal REST API does not accept form data, only  a JSON string which for this particular call must be part of a multitype content string. See the documentation you link to for what that string should look like; you are not posting such a string, as clearly shown from your logs.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, you can show me how to convert this cURL to regular post request?

Comment: It is very simple, you need to build a string with the appropriate format for a "multipart/related" MIME message (specifically), and post that string as your data. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905363/create-file-with-google-drive-api-v3-javascript/35182924#35182924 , you can search for others. Make sure they are for "multipart/related", put this in quotes when you search.