# Need help for setting up an API to read files from my Google Drive

Tags: javascript, api, google-drive-api

To keep this simple, here is what I want my end result to be: I want an html page that uses javascript to read and play videos that I have stored in one of my Google Drive folders.

I very recently learned about promises and fetching APIs in javascript so I am VERY new to it and cannot figure out how to do this, the documentation google provides is pure gibberish to me. And whenever I try to watch a youtube video they always write about 100 lines of extra code that I have to freaking clue what it does.

Ideally I could just get a single url with a couple variables so I can search my drive for specific videos in specific folders and play them. I think I am asking way too much, could anyone help me please?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create File with Google Drive Api v3 (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905363/create-file-with-google-drive-api-v3-javascript)